# Solving Transport Equation with Velocity Switch using Tempered Distributions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, distribution-theory, schwartz-space, step-function

Imagine we have the following two transport problems. The first is well known and can be solved using the Fourier transform, but I do not know how to solve the second one.

#### Problem 1: With Constant Velocity

Let $v \in \mathbb{R}$ be a constant we have:
\begin{align*}
    \partial_t u(x,t) = -v\partial_x u(x,t) \ , \quad (x,t) \in \mathbb{R} \times [0,\infty) \ .
\end{align*}
with the the initial condition $u(x,0) = \phi(x)$, where $\phi$ is a Schwartz function.

#### Solution to problem 1:

We will solve this using the Fourier transform, where $\mathcal{F}_x$ denote the Fourier transform with respect to the $x$ variable, $\mathcal{F}^{-1}_x$ is the inverse and we use the notation $\hat{u}(k,t) = (\mathcal{F}_x u)(k,t)$. We take the Fourier transform on both side:
\begin{align*}
    (\mathcal{F}_x \partial_t u)(k,t) &= -v(\mathcal{F}_x \partial_x u)(k,t) \\
    \partial_t \hat{u}(k,t) &= -ikv \hat{u}(k,t) \\
    \hat{u}(k,t) &= \hat{\phi}(x)\exp{(-ikvt)} \ .
\end{align*}
We now take the inverse Fourier transform:
\begin{align*}
    \mathcal{F}^{-1}_x \hat{u}(k,t) &= \mathcal{F}^{-1}_x \hat{\phi}(x)\exp{(-ikvt)}
\end{align*}
where we have $\mathcal{F}^{-1}_x \hat{u}(k,t) = u(x,t)$ for the left hand side and for the right hand side we have
\begin{align*}
    \mathcal{F}^{-1}_x \hat{\phi}(x)\exp{(-ikvt)} &= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{\phi}(x)\exp{(-ikvt)} \exp(ikx) \ dk \\
    &= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{\phi}(x) \exp{(-ik(x-vt))} \ dk \\
    &= \phi(x-vt) \ .
\end{align*}
Hence we conclude that the solution to the transport equation is:
\begin{align*}
    u(x,t) = \phi(x-vt) \ , \quad (x,t) \in \mathbb{R} \times [0, \infty) \ .
\end{align*}

#### Problem 2: With Velocity Switch

Let $v \in \mathbb{R}$ be a constant we have:
\begin{align*}
    \partial_t u(x,t) = -vH(t)\partial_x u(x,t) \ , \quad (x,t) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \ .
\end{align*}
with the the initial condition $u(x,t) = \phi(x)$ for all $t \leq 0$, where $\phi$ is a Schwartz function. Here $H(t)$ is the Heaviside step function:
\begin{align*}
    H(t) = \begin{cases}
    \ 1 \ , \quad t\geq 0 . \\
    \ 0 \ , \quad t < 0 .
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
My intuition tells me that these two problems should be equivalent so I would expect the solution to the second problem to be:
\begin{align*}
    u(x,t) = \phi(x-H(t)vt) \ , \quad (x,t) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \ .
\end{align*}
I will like to show this using Tempered Distributions, but alternative approaches are also welcome. Just as a quick disclaimer this is a problem I made up myself, so it may be an ill-posed problem.

#### Solution Attempt:

As in problem 1 we start by taking the Fourier transform with respect to $x$ then we have
\begin{align*}
    (\mathcal{F}_x \partial_t u)(k,t) &= -vH(t)(\mathcal{F}_x \partial_x u)(k,t) \\
    \partial_t \hat{u}(k,t) &= -ikvH(t)\hat{u}(k,t) \ .
\end{align*}
We now take take the Fourier transform with respect to time. We denote $g(k,t) = H(t)\hat{u}(k,t)$ and $f(k,t) = \hat{u}(k,t)$. Then we have
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F}_t\partial_t f(k,t) &= -ikv \mathcal{F}_t g(k,t) \\
i \omega \hat{f}(k,\omega) &= -ikv \hat{g}(k, \omega)
\end{align*}
Let $\phi(\omega)$ be an arbitrary Schwartz function. We multiply the above with $\phi(\omega)$ and integrate
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty i \omega \hat{f}(k,\omega) \phi(\omega) d\omega &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty -ikv \hat{g}(k, \omega) \phi(\omega) d\omega
\end{align*}
From here I am not really sure how to manipulate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems begin when you take $\mathcal{F}_t$.  Originally, you have $$\partial_t\hat{u}(k,t)=-ikvH(t)\hat{u}(k,t)$$  This is already solvable as in Problem 1: $$-ikvH(t)=\frac{\partial_t\hat{u}(k,t)}{\hat{u}(k,t)}=\partial_t{\ln{\!(\hat{u}(k,t))}}$$  Now integrate from $0$ to $t$: $$-ikvtH(t)=\ln{\!\left(\frac{\hat{u}(k,t)}{\hat{u}(k,0)}\right)}=\ln{\!\left(\frac{\hat{u}(k,t)}{\hat{\phi}(k)}\right)}$$  Thus $$\hat{u}(k,t)=\hat{\phi}(k)e^{-ikvtH(t)}$$  Taking the inverse transform, $$u(x,t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}{\hat{\phi(k)}e^{-ikvtH(t)}e^{ikx}\,dk}=\phi(x-vtH(t))$$ as you surmised.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jacob! That is a simple solution to the problem.

Comment: There is a small typo. The last integral should be with respect to the $k$ variable.

Comment: @MaxSmask: Fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(Because we are allowing $t$ to take negative values, which is nonstandard, I will rename it to $y$.)

The problem as it stands is ill-posed, because the derivatives break down at $y=0$. But we can look for a weak solution..

Let $\varphi:\Bbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be a smooth function with compact support. Multiply the entire equation by $\varphi$:
$$\varphi(x,y) H(y) c\partial_x u(x,y)+\varphi(x,y)\partial_yu(x,y)=0$$
Now integrate over $\Bbb R^2$:
$$c\int_\Bbb{R}\int_\Bbb{R}\varphi(x,y)H(y)\partial_x u(x,y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy+\int_\Bbb{R}\int_\Bbb{R}\varphi(x,y)\partial_y u(x,y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy=0$$
Now we use a little integration by parts. This can be rewritten as (exercise)
$$c\int_\Bbb{R}\int_\Bbb{R}u(x,y)H(y)\partial_x\varphi(x,y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy+\int_\Bbb{R}\int_\Bbb{R}u(x,y)\partial_y\varphi(x,y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$$
Or as
$$\int_\Bbb R\int_{\Bbb R}(u\mathbf v\cdot\nabla\varphi)(x,y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy=0$$
Where $\mathbf  v(x,y)=\big(cH(y),1\big)$. Now recall the product rule for divergence:
$$\nabla\cdot (f \mathbf u)=f\nabla\cdot\mathbf u+\mathbf u\cdot \nabla f$$
But clearly $\nabla\cdot \mathbf v=0$ hence our integral becomes
$$\int_\Bbb R\int_\Bbb R \big(u\nabla\cdot (\varphi \mathbf v)\big)(x,y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy=0$$
This is the weak form of our PDE. Let's see if your trial solution of $u(x,y)=u_0(x-H(y)cy)$ satisfies this weak form, and assume that $u_0$ is a smooth Schwartz function.
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\big(u\nabla\cdot(\varphi \mathbf v)\big)(x,y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy   = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty u_0(x-H(y)cy)~\nabla\cdot(\varphi \mathbf v)(x,y)\mathrm dy\mathrm dx \\ =\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\left[\int_{-\infty}^0u_0(x)~\nabla\cdot (\varphi\mathbf v)(x,y)\mathrm dy+\int_0^\infty u_0(x-cy)~\nabla\cdot(\varphi\mathbf v)\mathrm dy\right]\mathrm dx$$
Recall
$$\nabla\cdot(\varphi \mathbf v)(x,y)=cH(y)\partial_x\varphi(x,y)+\partial_y\varphi(x,y)$$
So we can simplify this integral more to
$$=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\left[\int_{-\infty}^0u_0(x)~\partial_y\varphi(x,y)\mathrm dy+\int_0^\infty u_0(x-cy)~\big(c\partial_x\varphi(x,y)+\partial_y\varphi(x,y)\big)\mathrm dy\right]\mathrm dx$$

*Unfortunately I am now busy so I will have to come back to this at a later stage. Hopefully this is helpful in some way*

Comment: Thanks for you reply! You statement "But clearly $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{v} = 0$" does it not require that the derivative of $H(t)$ exists in the classical sense?

Comment: No. Only the $x$ derivative needs to exist for the first component, and $H(y)$ is constant in $x$.

Comment: arh sure thanks. :)